# Android studio gradle maven 'unexpected token' error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

this is my code. I had Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)error in this code.

I fixed gradle version to 8.1.1 and every other attempt. But I can't solve.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and I resolve it by repleace

```
         path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
```

to

```
         path = File("src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
```